# 新しくアプリを作る際に既存のframeworkを追加してビルドするとFramework not foundとエラーが出る

Tags: swift, xcode, framework

超初心者です。

新しくアプリを作る際に既存のframeworkを利用しようとしています。

既存のframeworkは以下のサイトからダウンロードしたプロジェクトで生成しました。
https://github.com/magickworx/PageMenuKitSwift

やったこと ※以下の一連の流れを撮影した動画 https://youtu.be/GgjhPWOeoVg

１．上記のURLからダウンロードしたプロジェクトを開き、Build TargetにPageMenuKitFatBinary を指定して Build を実行し、PageMenuKit.framework が作成されました。

２．Create a new Xcode projectより、Single View Appを選択し、NewsAPPという名前で新規プロジェクトを作成しました。

３．新規プロジェクトのGeneralという項目のEmbedded Binariesの欄で＋ボタンを押し、PageMenuKit.frameworkを追加しました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

発生している問題

上記の手順を踏んだ後、ビルドをしたら、framework not found PageMenuKitとエラーが出てしまいました。このエラーを解決するにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: マルチポスト - https://teratail.com/questions/207625

Comment: まずFramework Search Pathsを変更したところが間違っています。Framework Search Pathはフレームワーク自体の場所を設定するのではなく、フレームワークが存在する「ディレクトリ」を指定します。
要するに１つ上の階層を指定する必要があって、元のパスであっていたのをわざわざ書き換えてしまっています。Xcodeは基本的にEmbedded Binariesにフレームワークを追加した場合は自動的に親ディレクトリをFramework Search Pathに設定します。
それがもともと正しくFramework Search Pathsが設定されていた理由です。なのでFramework Search Pathsを元に戻してください。あと見たところフレームワークのビルドは正常に完了していないのでおそらく別のエラーが出るのでそうなったらまた教えてください。

Comment: とりあえず、エラーが消えてビルドが成功するところまでは行きましたが、ビルドしても真っ白な画面しか表示されないという状態が発生しているので、改めて質問をさせていただきます。